# How to concatenate two values while adding zeros to the right in the second value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to concatenate the values of the two columns like `VALUE_A.VALUE_B` in SQL Server 2014, but the second value (`VALUE_B`) must have 4 decimals completing with 0 to the right when VALUE_B as two digits, and one zero to the left and the two to the right when it has one digit, for example:

- First row = 2031323.2200
- Row 24 = 201422.0200

| VALUE_A | VALUE_B | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2031323 | 22 | 1 |
| 3371331 | 75 | 1 |
| 4399213 | 52 | 1 |
| 4910001 | 46 | 1 |
| 2163036 | 38 | 1 |
| 1514817 | 91 | 1 |
| 2786338 | 36 | 1 |
| 3724760 | 35 | 1 |
| 3769556 | 13 | 1 |
| 3812410 | 28 | 1 |
| 4415600 | 54 | 1 |
| 1018894 | 95 | 1 |
| 3870688 | 43 | 1 |
| 3702609 | 87 | 1 |
| 3410337 | 79 | 1 |
| 1452983 | 52 | 1 |
| 3929430 | 69 | 1 |
| 1732252 | 44 | 1 |
| 4145563 | 85 | 1 |
| 448940 | 48 | 1 |
| 102980 | 20 | 1 |
| 479984 | 47 | 1 |
| 395812 | 84 | 1 |
| 201422 | 2 | 1 |
| 6023489 | 08 | 1 |
| 348325 | 29 | 1 |
| 2803 | 86 | 1 |
| 56077 | 0 | 1 |

I will need to use this concatenated value in another query to make operations, for example:

```
SELECT 
    VALUE_C + (CONVERT(float, CONCAT(RTRIM(CONVERT(char, VALUE_A)), '.' , RTRIM(CONVERT(char, VALUE_B))) 
FROM TABLE X
```

If the VALUE_C is 10.5100, the operation should be "10.5100 + 2031323.2200".

Another problem I'm facing with the operation is checking the SUM of the concatenated value per ID, the correct SUM for ID = 1 should be 68220986.6800, but it's returning 68164910.580000.

Example:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CONVERT(decimal(15, 4), CONVERT(varchar(10), VALUE_A) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(4), VALUE_B) + '00')) 
FROM X 
WHERE ID = 1
```

Here's the SUM of the same data but on Excel:

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Don't do this: `convert(char` use `varchar` and _specify a length_. In SQL Server you shouldn't be trying to define "string of any length" because it is not always going to be the same and it [leads to bad surprises](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Not sure how it's possible the output for ID = 1 could _possibly_ be `68220986` or `68164910` or how you're getting 6 decimal places with the code provided. The sum of `VALUE_A` on its own is `82883220`. Either you're querying a different data set or running a different query or both. Can you _please_ [create a fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) so we can all troubleshoot the same query against the same data.

Comment: The SUM of the same data on Excel is 68220986.6800, which is the value expected by the users, I added the pic on the main question.

Comment: Well in Excel for example you have a value `448940` and in the sample data in the question you added a `1` to it - `4489401` - which will obviously change the outcome. You might want to check and make sure that your C and V keys are not malfunctioning.

Comment: By following @AaronBertrand's point and removing the trailing `1` from `VALUE_A` in row 20-24, it's possible to get `68220986.68`

Comment: Sorry, I messed that up that 1 in those rows when coping, but I found part of the problem, the VALUE_B sometimes has only 1 digit, and when that happens, the value should have one zero to the left, like if it's 1, it should be 0100.

Answer (score 3):

Not totally clear on your requirements but something like this should be close enough.

```
select convert(decimal(15,4), convert(varchar(10), VALUE_A) + '.' + convert(varchar(4), VALUE_B) + '00')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the sum in this case is still wrong, it's returning 68164910.5800, it should be 68220986.6800:

`select SUM(convert(decimal(15,4), convert(varchar(10), VALUE_A) + '.' + convert(varchar(4), VALUE_B) + '00')) FROM X`

Comment: Here it is:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3106e87e4da7759a24be4715665328ed

Comment: @ViNi your sql fiddle makes no sense. Just taking the sum of the first column is 82883220. How did you come up with value that you expect as output from that data?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution which appears to give the right answer. It assumes that the base data types for `VALUE_A` and `VALUE_B` are in the `int` family, as in the dbfiddles linked in the comments:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CONVERT(decimal(20,4), VALUE_A + (VALUE_B * 0.01)))
FROM X 
WHERE ID = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a7653ecf78af69f97c14d4dc797e8a77)

(also assumes that the figures in the OP are incorrect, and rows 20-24 should have the last digit of `VALUE_A` discarded)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is something like this. But be careful, it only works if `value_b` is always 2 digits:

```
DECLARE @start TABLE (
    VALUE_A INT,
    VALUE_B INT,
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @start VALUES
  (2031323,     22,     1)
, (3371331,     75,     1)
, (4399213,     52,     1)
, (4910001,     46,     1)
, (2163036,     38,     1)
, (1514817,     91,     1)
, (2786338,     36,     1)
, (3724760,     35,     1)
, (3769556,     13,     1)
, (3812410,     28,     1)
, (4415600,     54,     1)
, (1018894,     95,     1)
, (3870688,     43,     1)
, (3702609,     87,     1)
, (3410337,     79,     1)
, (1452983,     52,     1)
, (3929430,     69,     1)
, (1732252,     44,     1)
, (4145563,     85,     1)
, (4489401,     48,     1)
, (1029801,     20,     1)
, (4799841,     47,     1)
, (3958121,     84,     1)
, (2014221,     02,     1)
, (6023489,     08,     1)
, (348325,  29,     1)
, (2803,    86,     1)
, (56077,   00,     1)

select * from @start

DECLARE @tosum TABLE (
                vals decimal(18, 4)
            )
DECLARE @value_C decimal(18,4) = 10.5100

insert into @tosum (vals) select ((value_A + (value_B * 0.0100))+ value_C) from @start where id = 1 

Select * from @tosum
select totalsum = sum(vals) from @tosum
```

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation as to why it works as well as showing a working solution.

Comment: oh you're right! I'll take more time to explain my answers, ty! @DaleK